# If $DX=5$ find E((2+X)^2).

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So, if DX=5, then

$$E((2+X)^2)=E(4+4X+X^2)=E(4)+4EX+EX^2=4+4EX+EX^2$$

$$DX=E(X-EX)^2=E(X^2-2XEX+(EX)^2)=5$$

$$DX=EX^2-2(EX)^2+(EX)^2=EX^2-(EX)^2=5$$

$$EX^2=5+(EX)^2$$

$$E((2+X)^2)=9+4EX+(EX)^2$$

So, I just rewrote the expression, but I don't know how to get a value from there.

Comment: To clarify, $D(X)$ is the variance of $X$?

Comment: Why do you find variance if it is needed to find expectation?

Comment: Your very first equation is incorrect. Firstly, $(2+X)^2$ equals $4 + 4X + X^2$ and not what you have written. This error propagates to the right side as well, Secondly, the rightmost formula is missing an Expectation operator.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I rewrote my post.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes.

Comment: You _still_ are making mistakes since you now have lost the $(EX)^2$ term on the right side of the last displayed equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu=\mathbb{E}[X]$, then
$$ \mathbb{E}[(X+2)^2]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu+\mu+2)^2]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2+2(X-\mu)(\mu+2)+(\mu+2)^2]$$
$$ =\mathrm{var}(X)+2(\mu+2)\mathbb{E}[X-\mu]+(\mu+2)^2=5+(\mu+2)^2$$
So only knowing $\mathrm{var}(X)$ is not enough to determine $\mathbb{E}[(X+2)^2]$, as translating $X$ would change $\mu$ but leave $\mathrm{var}(X)$ unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact $D[2+X] = D[X]$, or

$$E[(2+X)^2]-(E[2+X])^2=5$$

Thus,

$$E[(2+X)^2]=5+(E[2+X])^2= 5+ (2+E[X])^2$$